# PostgreSQL restoration throwing error : replication slot does not exist

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-backups, wal, pitr

Environment: `Postgresql 13.x` (dockerized)

I was trying to test the DR setup for PostgreSQL nodes.
pg_basebackup and wal_files archive was taken from the standby mode.

Done restoration on a new node by copying `pg_basebackup` and configured `postgresql.conf` to use `restore_command` pointing to walfiles archive.

```
#----------------------- RECOVERY CONFIGS -----------------------
restore_command = 'cp /db-restore/mydb/walfiles/%f "%p"'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
recovery_target_action = promote
```

- recovery seems to be fine. Some random `select` queries returning correct results.
- But logfile is throwing below error frequently.

```
2022-04-19 10:19:53 UTC [291] rep_usr@[unknown] ERROR:  replication slot "slot_name" does not exist
2022-04-19 10:19:58 UTC [296] rep_usr@[unknown] ERROR:  replication slot "slot_name" does not exist
```

- As I have taken backup from standby, is this restoration making new node as a standby and looking for the `replication_slot` it used in the previous generation?
- How can I make new node as a Master (remove replication_slot info)
- What are the proper steps to recover if the backup was taken from standby.
- I have 1 master and 2 standby nodes. And planning to take a backup from a standby. So is there any specific changes required for `archive_mode` and `archive_command` when using this on a standby node? Current commands:

```
archive_mode = always
archive_level = logical
archive_command = 'test ! -f /db-archives/walfiles/%f && cp %p /db-archives/walfiles/%f'"
```

Could someone help with this? Any pointers?

I am sure, db-backup will have info about replication_slot and connection_info as the `pg_basebackup` itself is a clone of entire DB. To revert configs, I am manually removing `postgresql.auto.conf` in `main` directory which contains above parameters.

- So how can I remove any other references of `replication_slot` if there are any in the DB backup?

Comment: Your error message does not look complete.  Were their more lines you have removed?

Answer (score 1):

These error messages don't seem to be thrown by recovery, but by some other tool that connects as database user `rep_usr`.

Create the replication slot if your application needs it!

Comment: I haven't connected any application to this new DB yet. 
And this `replication_slot` was created by me in Master as part of the replication setup.

I will revisit the entire configs, and restoration again. 

Would like to know if
`archive_mode=always` is the correct one to use on standby nodes if the backup is taken from there? 
Are any specific changes required to enable backup from standby? Backup and restore from Master didn't face any such issues.
Could you please direct me to the correct docs if I need to implement something specifically for standby nodes?

Comment: I am sure, db-backup will have info about `replication_slot` and `connection_info` as the pg_basebackup is a clone of DB.

To revert configs, I am manually removing `postgresql.auto.conf` which contains above parameters.
So how can I remove any other references of replication slot if there is any in the Database backup?

Comment: Then who is that `rep_usr` and what is it doing?

Comment: @Anto "I haven't connected any application to this new DB yet."  Well, then someone else has.  Expanding your log_line_prefix with things like appname and IP address could help figure that out.

Comment: I will set up a new restoration after blocking all connections. Will update this thread.
Thanks @jjanes Laurenz for your inputs.

Comment: Update.

I removed all configs and started with fresh. And removed `main/postgresql.auto.conf` which was present in the backup.

`main/postgresql.auto.conf` contains the configs used for `pg_basebackup` in standby nodes. (slot_name, and connect_info)

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

I removed all configs and started with fresh.

- removed `main/postgresql.auto.conf` which was present in the backup.
- `main/postgresql.auto.conf` is present in standby nodes when we take `pg_basebackup`. contains the configs used for pg_basebackup in standby nodes. (slot_name, and connect_info).

As I was restoring backup from standby to a Master, I don't need that `postgresql.auto.conf`.